# Javascript prototype undefined instead of inherited?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
function test() {
    this.a = {
        b: 4
    };
}

test.prototype.a = {
    c: 5
};

var example = new test();
```

Why is `example.a.c == undefined`?

Shouldn't it inherit the prototype and return `5`?

---

If this isn't possible, is there some way to add code to return the prototype?:

```
function test() {
    this.a = {
        b: 4,
        c: *this.return.prototype*
    };
}
```

Comment: Your prototype would work for `example.a.c`, except that `this.a` takes precedence over `test.prototype.a`.

Comment: @Barmar so it's not like $.extend() with 2 objects that create a new object a = {b: 4, c: 5};?

Comment: That's correct, the prototype isn't merged recursively.

Comment: You could define a getter for `a.c` that returns `this.prototype.a.c`.

Comment: @Barmar how would a call for that look like?

Comment: How should I define a getter like that? If you could post an answer with that I would be thankfull :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a getter for `a.c` that accesses the prototype.

```js
function test() {
  this.a = {
    b: 4,
    get c() {
      return test.prototype.a.c;
    }
  };
}

test.prototype.a = {
  c: 5
};

var example = new test();
console.log(example.a.b);
console.log(example.a.c);
// update prototype
test.prototype.a.c = 10;
console.log(example.a.c);
```

Answer (score 2):

`example.a` either references one object or the other, you can't directly make it retrieve properties from different objects.

What I would do is making `example.a` an object which inherits from the other one:

```js
function test() {
  this.a = Object.create(test.a_proto);
  this.a.b = 4;
}
test.a_proto = {
  c: 5
};
var example = new test();
console.log(example.a.b); // 4 (own)
console.log(example.a.c); // 5 (inherited)
```

Comment: What happens in this case if he changes `test.a_proto.c` after creating `example`? Will it continue to use the inherited prototype, or did it make a copy when you called `Object.create(test.a_proto)`?

Comment: I just tried it, and it continues to inherit from the proto. Nice.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, changes in `test.a_proto`'s properties will be inherited. But replacing `test.a_proto` itself won't.

Answer (score -1):

When you visit 'a' , it firstly find in example. If not find ,it will try to find  'a' in example construct's prototype.So it try to visit test.ptototype.c.So your code can't find examlpe.c.I think you can change your code like this.

```
function test() {
    this.a = {
        b: 4
    };
}
test.prototype.c = 5;
var example = new test();
console.log(example.c);//print 5
```

Comment: He wants `example.a.c`, not `example.c`.